# DC Motor Power Amplifier issue

Tags: transistors, operational-amplifier, dc-motor

i built this DC motor power amplifier to drive the motor in both directions using an analog signal (from -1 volt to 1 volt via the potentiometer ) , the motor i use is rated for 24 volts and draws around 400mA at no load , however, when i tested it only one direction works fine ( the NPN TIP142 side) with no significant heat , the other side however doesn't drive the motor all the way to 10 volts and the PNP transistor becomes hot real fast, i replaced it with another tip147 but still got the same results, any idea what maybe causing this?
[image: schematic]

Update 1: I inserted a resistor in series with the PNP gate and it enhanced the motor's performance , however the oscillations still exist , should i also consider an RC snubber ??

Comment: Try reversing the wires to your motor to see if the "bad" direction changes. If the bad direction doesn't change then it's likely to be a mechanical load problem in one direction.

Comment: Do you have a scope?  You are likely oscillating because the PNP side has much higher current gain.  A quick test would be to add a resistor between the op amp and bases of the two TIPs and take your feedback from the output of the op amp rather than the motor.

Comment: @Andyaka i changed the motor leads and still have the same problem only in another direction, so its not a mechanical issue , thanks for your feedback though.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead if i remove the feedback from the motor , wouldnt that cause a cross-over distortion ? i need the linearity in my application, will try to add resistors and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have a wiring error, or that the motor is actually capable of being driven in both directions, and similar issues, the schematic you show here appears to be a legitimate circuit for driving the motor as you desire.

However, this same circuit, in its many disguises, can present a number of practical problems. I have experienced these in the past, so I speak from actual case histories.

The main problem is that the circuit has a tendency to oscillate, resulting in both output transistors being turned on at the same time. When both transistor conduct simultaneously, they essentially create a short circuit across the power supply and will get very hot. This is due to frequency response of the transistors, base capacitance and similar dynamic properties. Also, the unity gain follower which is the kernel of this topology has a very high natural bandwidth - essentially the "gain-bandwidth" of the amplifier. All these factors promote oscillation.

There are a few common fixes for this condition:

A: Place ferrite beads on the conductors leading to the collectors of each transistor. Or, use wired ferrite beads and place them in series with the collectors. It doesn't hurt to give the emitters the same treatment.

B. Connect small series resistors in each transistors base drive connection.

C. Connect a resistor from the common connection of the two transistor bases to ground. Size the resistor so it is the largest load (i.e. smallest resistance) the TL084 can drive without hampering operation of the remaining circuitry.

D. Limit the bandwidth of the core unity gain amplifier. There are a few ways to do this, but it can depend on which op-amp you are using. So check the op-amps data sheet for a recommendation on limiting bandwidth of the unity-gain hook-up of the specific op-amp. (Some op-amps are not designed for unity-gain operation. Check the data sheet for the term "unity-gain stable" or similar which indicates its OK to use the op-amp in this kind of topology.

E. Limit the bandwidth of the input signal to the unity-gain stage. In your case you would put a big whopping capacitor across R25. Something like a few micro-farads wouldn't be out of the question. But it has to be a non-polarized cap for your application. It wouldn't hurt to connect a cap from the pot wiper to ground either if that's convenient for the wiring in your equipment.

F. Try a different op-amp. You need one that can both source and sink output current. Many "single supply voltage" op-amps cannot do this. (I'm not sure about this one.)

You may need to do some or all of the above to tame your circuit!

I also notice that you are using a quad op-amp. What are the other sections doing? If nothing, their inputs should be tied off so that the associated outputs are saturated in one direction or the other. Don't tie both to ground, as this will put the open-loop op-amp into the linear operating range, and that can cause other problems. If the other sections are used, consider segregating them to another device entirely.

On this last point: when designing op-amp circuits, IMHO, its better to use two dual op-amps then one quad op-amp. Mainly, this is for PC-layout reasons. But also there is a much larger choice of dual op-amps than quad op-amps. 98% of all dual op-amps have the same pin-out, so this makes it easy to swap out different op-amps in your breadboard/prototype to optimize the selection if that becomes necessary. And, there's usually little or no cost impact created by two duals compared to one quad. This circuit would be a good example of using this strategy. Don't get me wrong there are plenty of legitimate uses for quad amps, but avoid using them out of force of habit or for unconsidered reasons.

Comment: i will try all of these things today and let you know my progress , but one thing i want to mention is that yes the circuit oscillates alot and most likely shorting the two supplies together , but i ignored it because the npn transistor doesn't seem to have a problem with that and works pretty well, i will investigate more and post my findings .

Comment: Bersha, it's possible that one transistor could be affected more than the other. It depends on how the oscillation is actually occurring. You must concentrate on eliminating the oscillation. I see that you have posted this question again under a different title.

Comment: yes i did, the oscillation turned out to be the source of all my problems, inserting a cap across R24 solved most of the problem for me, but still some oscillations occur when the signal input is in the range between(-0.5 ~ 0 volts)